# Locking Output to Output Window in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, winapi, trace

My application sends debug data to the Output Window in Visual Studio using the `TRACE` macro.  Some of these output strings are built using several calls to the `TRACE` macro, as is shown in the following snippet of code:

```
BYTE i, len;

len = pMsg[APP_LEN_OFFSET] + sizeof(appPktHead_t) - APP_MSG_CODE_LEN;

TRACE(_T("%s: "), fnName);
TRACE(GetCmdIdStr( pMsg[APP_MSG_CODE_OFFSET] ));
TRACE(_T(" 0x"));

for ( i = 0; i < len; i++ )
{
    TRACE(_T("%.2X "), pMsg[i]);
}

TRACE(_T("\r\n"));
```

How can I either lock the output to the Output Window for the duration of this function, or send the entire string in a single call to `TRACE`?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a single string, before using the `TRACE` macro.

```
byMsgLen = pMsg[DEV_LEN_OFFSET] + sizeof(devPktHead_t) + sizeof(devPktTail_t);
cmd = pMsg[DEV_CMD_MSB_OFFSET];
cmd <<= 8;
cmd |= pMsg[DEV_CMD_LSB_OFFSET];
pCmdIdStr = GetCmdIdStr( cmd );
iPreOffset = ::wcsnlen_s(fnName, 128)       // function name
    + 2                                     // ": "
    + ::wcsnlen_s(pCmdIdStr, 128)           // command ID string
    + 3;                                    // " 0x"
iPostOffset = iPreOffset + byMsgLen * 3;    // "%.2X " (formatted: 2 hex-nibble bytes and space)
iStrLen = iPostOffset + 3;                  // "\r\n\0"
pBuf = (wchar_t *)malloc( iStrLen * sizeof(wchar_t) );

::swprintf_s( pBuf, iStrLen, _T("%s: %s 0x"), fnName, pCmdIdStr);

for ( i = iPreOffset; i < iPostOffset; i += 3 )
{
    ::swprintf_s( &(pBuf[i]), 4, _T("%.2X "), pMsg[j++] );
}

::swprintf_s( &(pBuf[i]), 3, _T("\r\n") );

TRACE( pBuf );

::free( pBuf );
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is a way to lock the output window in Visual Studio.  I think the easiest way to do this is to build up the entire message into a `std::stringstream` or `wchar_t[]` object and then output that single value to the `TRACE` macro

Been awhile since I used `stringstream` so there are likely a few errors here but the following should get you on the right track

```
std::stringstream stream;
stream << fnName << ": ";
stream << GetCmdIdStr( pMsg[APP_MSG_CODE_OFFSET] );
stream << " 0x";
for ( i = 0; i < len; i++ )
{
    stream << pMsg[i] << " ";
}

stream << "\r\n";
TRACE(stream.str().c_str());
```

Comment: @JaredPar: Thanks.  It sort-of works, but I'm getting some strange output in the Output Window now.  Take a look at this screen capture (http://tinypic.com/r/2v9b588/7).  The odd font is where the output string should be, but the only part of the string that get displayed is the function name, and the rest of it is scrambled.

Comment: @Jim it looks like the problem is a mixing of unicode and ASCII.  I would try `wstringstream` and see if that fixes the issue

Comment: @Jim Fell, the strange output is because it's treating the bytes as characters. Easy fix is to cast `pMsg[i]` to an int. Also, since you seem to be trying to output as hex, don't forget the std::hex modifier before you output the value.

Comment: @JaredPar:  Thanks.  I changed it to `wstringstream`, and it's working better now.  If I set a breakpoint at the `TRACE` macro, I can see the formatted string at `stream._Stringbuffer._Seekhigh`, and it appears that the string is not null-terminated when viewed in a Memory window.  I've tried `stream << "\r\n\0";` and `stream << "\r\n" << endl;` without success.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Jim, accoridng to the docs `stringstream` and `c_str` both should be returning NULL terminated string values.  Why do you think it's not null terminated?

Comment: @JaredPar: Please take a look at this screen capture (http://tinypic.com/r/2pq2hdk/7).  In the Memory 1 window you can see that there is no terminating null.

Comment: @JaredPar: I noticed something else that is interesting.  While `stream._Stringbuffer._Seekhigh` does contain a valid string (minus terminating null), the return value of `stream.str().c_str()` is not a valid pointer to a string at all (see Memory 2 window in last screen capture).

Comment: @JaredPar:  Thanks for the help.  I was able to build up the string using `swprintf_s`.  My answer is posted below, and I'm up-voting your response for confirming that I needed to use a single `TRACE` macro.